# Animation Doesn't Play

Tags: loops, animation, unity-game-engine

In unity i've made animation (animation window). It plays fine, but looping. So i went to project files, found animation, unchecked "Loop time", then my animation doesn't play at all. Ive watched so many videos, read a lot of tutorials, but that stuff "uncheck loop time " doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a trigger in the animator and then trigger it by code

```
GetComponent<Animator> ().SetTrigger ("yourtriggername");
```